# Undefined symbol when loading node addon after updating node.js from v8 to v12

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I have updated my node from v8.16.2 to v12.18.3.
When I'm trying now to load my addon I have this error:

`$ /usr/bin/node -e "require('/home/user1/addon.node')"`

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1187
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /home/user1/addon.node: undefined symbol:
_ZNK2v88Function11NewInstanceEiPNS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1187:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
```

I've found out that this undefined symbol `_ZNK2v88Function11NewInstanceEiPNS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE` was previously defined in the node binary itself (in node v8 before update to node v12).
I have not changed the way I build my node. That is the parameters for the script "configure" did not change and they are the same for both node v8 and node v12.
However, now this missing symbol is not anymore defined in the node binary for node v12. Does anyone know why this happens?

For node v12 this symbol is not defined:

`$ readelf -Ws node | grep _ZNK2v88Function11NewInstanceEiPNS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE`

`(no any output)`

For node v8 this symbol is defined:

`$ readelf -Ws node |grep _ZNK2v88Function11NewInstanceEiPNS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE`

`66565: 00000000005167a8    84 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _ZNK2v88Function11NewInstanceEiPNS_5LocalINS_5ValueEEE`

Why is this symbol not anymore defined in node v12?

Thank you,
Aleksej.

Comment: there were quite a few changes between versions 8 and 12. it sounds like you're using nan to build the addon. maybe adding some more information about whether you're using nan, n-api, or node-addon-api would be helpful. if you're using nan then you will need to update the version of nan that you're using.

Comment: FWIW, **c++filt** shows the de-mangled name as: 
_v8::Function::NewInstance(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const_

Answer (score 1):

`v8::Function::NewInstance(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)` was removed in Node.js v10. The replacement takes a `v8::Local<v8::Context>` as its first argument: https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.15/d5/d54/classv8_1_1_function.html#aac8391b7c084a5b487954990fdc9acf4

You can get the context with `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->GetCurrentContext()` or, if you're using NAN, `Nan::GetCurrentContext()`.